# Python Pandas No Module Named Webencodings

Tags: python, html, pandas, spyder

I'm trying to load data from a web page ([Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_GDP_%28nominal%29)) using pandas read_html function. When i try this:

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_GDP_%28nominal%29'
mD = pd.read_html(url)
```

i got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "<ipython-input-14-1dee4ebbc8f2>", line 1, in <module>
  md = pd.read_html(url)

 File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 866, in read_html
  parse_dates, tupleize_cols, thousands, attrs, encoding)

 File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 718, in _parse
  parser = _parser_dispatch(flav)

 File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 663, in _parser_dispatch
  raise ImportError("html5lib not found, please install it")

ImportError: html5lib not found, please install it
```

but i supposedly already have installed the `html5lib` module as shown in this pic:

[image]

and here is another problem because when i try to load `html5lib` i got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "<ipython-input-2-69f09277bafa>", line 1, in <module>
  import html5lib

 File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\html5lib-0.99999999.dev0-py3.5.egg\html5lib\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
  from .html5parser import HTMLParser, parse, parseFragment

 File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\html5lib-0.99999999.dev0-py3.5.egg\html5lib\html5parser.py", line 6, in <module>
  from . import inputstream

 File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\html5lib-0.99999999.dev0-py3.5.egg\html5lib\inputstream.py", line 9, in <module>
  import webencodings

ImportError: No module named 'webencodings'
```

and this is where i'm stuck because can't find any way to install this module. Anyone has any idea of what is wrong?

By the way, I'm using Python 3.5 and the Spyder IDE.

Comment: How did you install `html5lib`? Was it using `pip`?

Answer (score 2):

Try installing the module using, pip install webencodings.

Comment: pip is for Python 2 and pip3 is for Python 3.